# Prove that $5|2^n +3$ $\iff$ $4|(n-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have to prove the statement that $5|2^n +3$ $\iff$ $4|(n-1)$. I have gotten somewhere with the $\Rightarrow$ direction, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

$5|2^n +3$ $\implies$ $2^n \equiv -3$mod $5$. Working in mod$5$, we see that $2^n$mod$5$ is only ever equal to $-3$mod$5$ iff $n=k+4$, for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. So the congruence is only true for $n=1,5,9,..,k+4$. If we take $n-1$, i.e, $0,4,8,...,k+3$, we see that it necessarily implies that $4|(n-1)$.

How correct is this thinking? How would I go about proving the reverse direction? Could I try a contrapositive proof?

Comment: Hint: $2^n \bmod 5 = 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, \dots$ is periodic of period 4.

Comment: $n=k+4$, for some $k∈Z$ doesn't really say anything. Did you mean $n=4k +1$

Comment: Two things are equivalent to each other if they are both equivalent to the same thing. Simplest is to prove the intermediate: $5\mid 2^n+3 \iff n=4k+1 \iff 4\mid (n-1)$. The rightmost equivalence is definitional, and the leftmost equivalence can be proved by cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It is based on the periodity of the last digit of the series of natural powers of 2

[image]

Comment: Please use MathJax, not images.